# pandas rolling_quantile bug?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statsmodels

i recently bumped an unexpected issue with pandas rolling funcs. *rolling_quantile* for example:

```
>> row = 10
>> col = 5
>> idx = pd.date_range(20100101,periods=row,freq='B')
>> a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(row*col).reshape((row,-1)),index=idx)
>> a
                   0           1           2           3           4
2010-01-01  0.341434    0.497274    0.596341    0.259909    0.872207
2010-01-04  0.222653    0.056723    0.064019    0.936307    0.785647
2010-01-05  0.179067    0.647165    0.931266    0.557698    0.713282
2010-01-06  0.049766    0.259756    0.945736    0.380948    0.282667
2010-01-07  0.385036    0.517609    0.575958    0.050758    0.850735
2010-01-08  0.628169    0.510453    0.325973    0.263361    0.444959
2010-01-11  0.099133    0.976571    0.602235    0.181185    0.506316
2010-01-12  0.987344    0.902289    0.080000    0.254695    0.753325
2010-01-13  0.759198    0.014548    0.139858    0.822900    0.251972
2010-01-14  0.404149    0.349788    0.038714    0.280568    0.197865

>> a.quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75],axis=0)
               0           1           2           3           4
0.25    0.189963    0.282264    0.094964    0.255999    0.323240
0.50    0.363235    0.503864    0.450966    0.271964    0.609799
0.75    0.572164    0.614776    0.600761    0.513510    0.777567

>> np.percentile(a,[25,50,75],axis=0)
[array([ 0.18996316,  0.28226404,  0.09496441,  0.25599853,  0.32323997]),
 array([ 0.36323529,  0.50386356,  0.45096554,  0.27196429,  0.60979881]),
 array([ 0.57216415,  0.61477607,  0.6007611 ,  0.51351021,  0.7775667 ])]

>> pd.rolling_quantile(a,row,0.25).tail(1)
                   0           1       2           3           4
2010-01-14  0.179067    0.259756    0.08    0.254695    0.282667
```

looks like *pandas.DataFrame.quantile* member func is consistent with the *numpy.percentile* func.  however the *pandas.rolling_quantile* func returns diff results.  reduce the row number to 5, the problem will be gone (all three methods return the same results).  any thoughts?

ps: i also tested *rolling_std* func which will "random" generate error with 10^-7 ~ 10^-8 scales for long (row-wise) pandas.DataFrames

python environment:

- *python 3.4.2*
- *cython 0.21.1*
- *numpy 1.8.2*
- *scipy 0.14.0*
- *pandas 0.15.1*
- *statsmodels 0.6.0*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a pandas bug so ought to be filed on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: at the beginning i was not sure if it was a bug or not.  since no one could answer here, i filed a new issue in github. thx anyway

Comment: can't hurt to xpost :), I confess I didn't look too closely (will look back later)

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9413), the problem seems to be that the `rolling_quantile()` function (now in pandas 0.18 is `rolling().quantile()`) does not interpolate, it simply uses the nearest point.

A workaround is to apply the numpy percentile function after rolling:

```
a.rolling(row).apply(func=np.percentile, args=(25,)).tail(1)
```

which gives the correct interpolated results.

Answer (score 0):

This has be fixed in pandas 0.21.0. I just tried it. BTW, 0.20.3 hasn't fixed it.  The fix is here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16247